# Refs inside arrays unexpected behavior

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I am trying to use an `v-model` with a custom component. More specifically I was using an `v-for` to generate a list of elements based on infomations in an array. In practice, the components did not behave as I expected... the problem seems to arise from how the `ref`(s) are treated and I can't find the reason for it nor a solution.

This is my test code, from which I expect the same result on both rows, but it doesn't:

```js
// App.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import CustomInput from './CustomInput.vue'
  
const message = ref('hello')
const myArr = [message]
 
</script>

<template>
  <CustomInput v-model="message" /> {{ message }}
  <br/>
  <CustomInput v-model="myArr[0]" /> {{ myArr[0] }}
</template>
```

```js
// CustomInput.vue
<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<template>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>
```

[Playground Project](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UE1rg0AQ/SvDEtBAqj2LCQ2lh9566sX1YOOYCu4Hu6tQxP/eWZWNhJDb7rz35r03IztrnQw9sozl9mJa7cCi6/WJy1ZoZRyMYLCBCRqjBEREjQL03lunxKfUvVvhJN3M/F4iA3B5UdI6EGhtdUU4+pVx9Itdp6J9QP/OxhBWrLSSpFzm6RKLAtHHodBd5ZB+APnWf3gRqsbuyNkq5wzSE4xjcJ2mWfRj0qdqn6J4LW/ydTDr8zQkYAd21/XBDWtsWolfRmkbF9Hs8V11dJaSai/gh2idB3td09rsjvOsfuuN/QsgG7zCxw9yzhbobaYRtENyih/4HGCHA0qXuMpckar46X7R+1ttS0//y73Frw==)

I premise that I am new to Vue, and have only read a small part of the documentation at the moment, so I apologize if there is anything I missed that would allow a simple and obvious solution to the question.

I tried wrapping the array in a `ref` or `reactive` (read around) but it doesn't seem to work.

I am sure there are solutions such as hardcoding the components to solve my original problem. But mine is mainly an educational question, so the code shown above I think extrapolates well to the problem I'm interested in. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Does this help? [SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqFUs1qwkAQfpVhEaKQGvQYVCql0F5KT724PaRmokuT3WWzCUjMu3c2G2MQ294y8/3MfLNp2FbreV0hi9mq3BuhLZRoK73hUhRaGQsNGMyghcyoAgKiBgP0VJVWFa9SV7aH59Go53yJDMDlXsnSQoFlmRwQ1s5yGhwxz1UwG9DT1pge2zlZI9IYFuFFFoOs8jyEo8pTNDFw9tJ9LThrw4G//Je/JD6XnzSXFltFPjXlpcJiofPEIlUAq3G8+qFQKeZrznp3ziDaQNMMoVoyJdGXibz64kXSTBkSCuqAkD4nyeNvPPXtuUg562S/ju1o19kxee/RR7ugvuoWa5oxH85nCN6UxKBtrwtGo7SjgoXs5g3v/BspZkLiu1G6nO6CbsePJKfndmf14HMhrAMrnZJtfMP56+7CDfbHiGuncFcf5Jx56LGjETRBmjS9MyeECdYo7dwm5oAUxXVnXu9uMA7d/gAHGg4I)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a ref used in your `<template>` code is automatically "unwrapped", so `v-model="message"` actually becomes `v-model="message.value"`, where `.value` is the inner value `'hello'`.

With `v-model="myArr[0]"` you're basically hiding the fact that it's a ref by assigning an array index. Vue isn't *that* smart to know it's a ref in this case, which results in the entire ref proxy object being assigned to the v-model. This is why you see `[object Object]` in the input instead of the inner value.  The simple fix is to unwrap the value yourself by specifying `.value`

```html
<CustomInput v-model="myArr[0].value" /> {{ myArr[0].value }}
```

[updated Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UEtrg0AQ/ivDEtBAqj2LCQ2lh9566sX1YOOYCu6DfQhF/O+dVRETQm678z1nBnbWOuk9sozl9mJa7cCi8/rEZSu0Mg4GMNjACI1RAiKiRiv07q1T4lNq7xY4STez4EtkAC4vSloHAq2trgjHYBlHv9h1Ktqv6N/ZGMKKhVaSlMs8nWtRIfo4FLqrHNIPIN/m9y9C1dgdOVvknEF6gmFYU8dxEv2Y9Kk6tChey6SvOr8xuRlPXnm6tmEHdrf3g3vW2LQSv4zSNi6iKe87mEUlnWAGP0TrAuh1TbbZHefZKdoQHF4A2VQxrLLKOZuht4lG0A4pKX6Qc4Ad9ihd4ipzRVolTPezPtxtu/T4D5IwykU=)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a reactive variable in Vue, so reactive rendering|update will not be available for such variable. Plus you have to use `message.value` to reference the value of `message` ref inside the script.

```js
const myArr = [message]
```

If you want to use multiple inputs and track their inputs here is one workaround:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import CustomInput from './CustomInput.vue'
  
const myArr = ref([
  {id: 1, message: null, holder: "Holder1"},
  {id: 2, message: null, holder: "Holder2"}
])
</script>

<template>
  <CustomInput v-model="message" /> {{ message }}
  <br/>
  <template v-for="item in myArr" :key="item.id">
    <CustomInput v-model="item.message" :placeholder="item.holder" />{{item.message || 'None'}}<br/>
  </template>
</template>
```

Example at [Vue Sfc Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqFUsFqwkAQ/ZVhKUQhTdBjUKmUQnspPfXierBm1KWb3WWzESTm3zubjTGIbW+Zee/Nm3nZmi2NSY4VsozNyq0VxkGJrjILrkRhtHVQg8UdNLCzuoCIqFEPPVel08WbMpXr4CQd9PxcIgNwtdWqdFBgWW72CHM/chQdUEodjXv0tLS2w1ZeVos8g0l8kWWgKiljOGiZo82As9f2a8JZE/f86b/8KfG5Wg99lXYHtMF+1cmT40ZWuA4sLTGRej8acmkAXTZLQ2wUGBUOCyM3DqkCmA3zOT4WOkc556ybzxmkC6jrPpWGtiLRl02D+jKLpDttSSioA0KFoEiefeOpayci56yV/Wrb0q7eGc3eYsjmgoaqXayuh3w4nyF61wqjprkumA6uHRQsZjeP4M7jynEnFH5YbcrRKmp3/PR5R/6/BPClEM6DlclpbHbD+St34Y1DGFn7F33qvZyzAD21NIIekJxGd3xieMAjKpe4jd0jneK746D3GQyPbn4A010mtA==)

Comment: Thank you for going into more detail about my problem. Your solution helped me understand cases, but specifically I am in this situation: https://shorturl.at/cgsI4 . The problem is that I would like the changes from the input to be propagated down to `myRefs`...

Comment: why you want two `reactives` to track the inputs? You can track multiple inputs with a single one as mentioned in my above example.

Comment: Because in the rest of the app I have to access `prop{n}` a lot, and it's completely unlinked from the logic of `myArr`, which is only used to generate the inputs for these values. I would have liked to keep these values separate, mainly for logical reasons.

Comment: IMHO, this violates single source of truth and adds complexity to the code. You can construct computed methods to get desired prop.

Comment: I agree with you. However, mine is a question of a strong educational nature, and clearly this is a edge case. But I was wondering in case in a particularly complex scenario I am faced with this requirement how I should deal with it. Also I am trying to understand how Vue reasons about this, in fact I am having difficulty understanding why the `ref` is "unboxed" inside `myArr`...

Comment: Here is my final try for the question: [VueSfcEx](https://shorturl.at/LSVX0)